# Why Does 7zip give the error that certain files inside a zip downloaded from Dropbox are corrupted when they clearly are not?

Tags: zip, dropbox, 7-zip

My wife has a ton of data that she has worked on over the course of a decade saved on Dropbox, and we are trying to back this up to a local external drive so that we have two copies. I've downloaded all the data in chunks (from the top level folder, Dropbox complains it would be zipping too many folders), and when I try to extract some using 7zip, 7zip will complain that a handful of the files inside the zip are corrupted.

I can use the windows file explorer to go into the compressed folder and open the supposedly corrupted files (in the test case, a png file), and they open perfectly fine. It looks like exactly the file I expect.

This error is annoying because it's just a handful of files that now I have to go through and manually pull out of the zip file. Is there any way to fix 7zip so that it doesn't make this mistake? Or is there a better archive tool to use?

I can't use the windows vanilla zip utility to extract the files because that one complains that some file path names are too long (I've already changed my registry to allow long file paths, but the zip tool itself still complains about the length of the file paths).

Comment: Why don't you re-download these files? Perhaps they are truly corrupted a bit. The long path problem is easily fixed by copying the files elsewhere.

Comment: Are the zip-files about 2 GB (or larger) in size? That may cause some issues although 7zip can handle them just fine normally. As @harrymc just mentioned: Just re-downloading the few problem files as a separate zip might be less hassle than trying to extract them from the largish zip-files using another tool.
I wonder if WinRar (that can also extract zip-files) finds them corrupt too?

Comment: I’m not sure I follow. Why not just use the regular Dropbox client, then copy the local Dropbox folder to wherever?

Comment: @Tonny that may end up being the solution, but I'd rather the tool work. Some of the zips range from a few MB to 70GB in size.

Comment: @DanielB the client is broken, it has been trying to sync for a month now no matter how many times we reboot, reinstall, check for updates, etc. Meanwhile I can download zips through the web in a matter of hours.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas funny

Comment: You should add this vital information to your question! Maybe look into _rclone_, it can access Dropbox.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas ain't nobody got time for that

Comment: just as an aside, I do recommend avoiding using zip files (or really any other container format, but especially compressed ones) for long term archival. you are putting all your eggs in a basket and if that basket suffers a tiny bit of bitrot in the right places, ALL the eggs are gone.

Comment: @FrankThomas If you absolutely have to use container files for archiving at least create a PAR2 recovery set (with 15% redundancy or so) for each archive file. That way you can verify and repair bitrot damage if necessary. I had a case where a client insisted on rarring old projects and burning those rars to DVD for 25 years of data-retention. After 6-7 years the first DVDs (not archival grade ones of course, too expensive) started to have some bitrot. Easily repairable with the PARs that I had the foresight to add to the DVDs. The ones made before my time without PARs had to be trashed.

Comment: man, par2. its been a while. I miss usenet. sucks they killed it.

Comment: @FrankThomas - I'm still on usenet ;)) …and one lesson from usenet is never try to download large zips over HTTP[s] because of local ISP caching. Use a download manager that will split & concat the files locally. JDownloader is my weapon of choice in that these days. Java-based, multi-platform.

Comment: @FrankThomas the files are unzipped in dropbox. Dropbox zips them before I can download them through the web browser. The dropbox client that comes with a sync feature is broken on my wife's computer and I've tried every troubleshooting technique I can think of or have found on the web.